# Anchor tag disrupting flexbox command (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, anchor, href

I'm trying to use flexbox (justify-content: space-between;) to push the Motorola logo to the left and the red block (nav-bar) to the right. It actually works pretty well as long as there is no anchor tag involved. However, I need anchor tags so that visitors can actually click on each item of the nav-bar and get to the respective section of the website. 
How can I make justify-content work without removing the anchor tags?

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <img id="header-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Motorola_Logo_White.png" alt="This is Motorolas Logo">
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <div id="nav1" class="nav-link"><a href="#prices">Prices</div>
    <div id="nav2" class="nav-link"><a href="#prices">Specs</div>
    <div id="nav3" class="nav-link"><a href="#prices">Reviews</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
}

#header-img {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#nav-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here you can see it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gignu/pen/zYOMWgq)

Comment: by correctly closing your anchor at the end --> `</a>`

Comment: You should close the `<a href="#prices">Prices</a>` tags.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the anchor tag worked like the img tag, which you don't have to close...

Answer (score -2):

In cases where you have a flex container with left-aligned content - except one or more items you want to right-align, there is a shortcut using the `margin` property.

If you add the following rule to your existing styles:

```css
#nav-bar {
    margin-left: auto; /* Pushes the element right inside a flex container */
}
```

It should work as you want. You could even remove the `justify-content: space-between;` rule from your `#header` selector.